# In how many ways can $n$ passengers be distributed to $m$ available counters?

Tags: combinatorics

There are $n$ passengers on the airport that need to go through customs. To facilitate a fast processing there are $m$ available counters. In how many ways can the passengers be distributed among the available counters in case the order of passenger per counter does not matter?

Is it correct that we can apply a simple $nCr$ in this case? Since the order of passengers does not seem to matter, but just the distribution of passengers among the counters. Therefore resulting in $\binom nm$.

Comment: Note that $\binom{n}{m}$ is the number of ways of selecting $m$ objects when $n$ objects when order does not matter.  In this case, each of the $n$ passengers has $m$ choices.

Comment: There are $\displaystyle {n \choose n_{1}, n_{2}, \ldots, n_{m}}$ ways to distribute the passengers. The $\displaystyle \left\{\cdots\right\}$ is the multinomial. The [answer is given](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4595992/85343) by its sum over all configurations with $\displaystyle n_{1}\ + n_{2} + \cdots + n_{m} = n$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's first take a smaller example where there are only 2 passengers.
Each passenger can go to any of the $m$ counters. Therefore, a number of possibilities are(since order doesn't matter)

$ m \times m = m^2 $

Now similarly if we expand this case to $n$ passengers instead of 2 we get that each passenger has $m$ choices. So total possibilities would be,

$ m \times m \times m .... $ ( $n$ times) $= m^n$ which is your answer.

Comment: Notice that each of the $n$ customers has the choice of $m$ counters.

Comment: Didn't really understand your point, could you elaborate?

Comment: The first passenger has a choice of $m$ counters.  The second passenger also has a choice of $m$ counters.  In how many ways can you distribute two passengers to $m$ counters.  Keep in mind that they can go to the same counter.

Comment: In this case, I believe it would $m^2$. As each has m choices. But if we were to generalize this as it is given in the question, the answer would be $m^n$ I get your point now. What have I done wrong?

Comment: The answer is indeed $m^n$.  The point is that each passenger has $m$ choices.  There is no need to consider whether or not a passenger will go to the same counter as a previous passenger.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I get it now, thanks! I took a very dirty and tedious approach.

Comment: You should edit your answer to explain the correct solution to the problem.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig done

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
Hereafter, $\ds{\bracks{\cdots}_{\cal I}}$ is a *Iverson's Bracket*.

---

The $\ds{\underline{answer}}$ is given by a sum which involve  multinomials. Namely,
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\sum_{\large c_{i}\ \in\ \mathbb{N}_{\geq 0}}{n! \over c_{1}!\ldots c_{m}!}\bracks{c_{1} + \cdots c_{m} = n}_{\cal I}} =
\sum_{\large c_{i}\ \in\ \mathbb{N}_{\geq 0}}{n! \over c_{1}!\ldots c_{m}!}\bracks{z^{n}}{z^{c_{1}\ +\ \cdots\ +\ c_{m}}}
\\[5mm] = & \
n!\bracks{z^{n}}\pars{\sum_{c\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{z^{c} \over c!}}^{m} =
n!\bracks{z^{n}}\pars{\expo{z}}^{m}
\\[5mm] = & \
n!\bracks{z^{n}}\expo{mz} = n!\pars{m^{n} \over n!} = \bbx{\color{#44f}{m^{n}}}\\ &
\end{align}